# Cómo definir rutas (Paths) en proyectos PHP (tanto para aplicaciones web como de línea de comandos)

Tags: php, rutas

## Esta pregunta es autorespondida.

En proyectos PHP (tanto para aplicaciones web como para la línea de comandos), ¿cuál es la manera de definir rutas (PATH) y por qué deberíamos evitar rutas estáticas?

```
include("c:/path/al/directorio/archivo.php");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definir rutas `(PATH)` en proyectos PHP, ya sea para aplicaciones web o de línea de comandos `(CLI)`, es esencial para garantizar la portabilidad y la escalabilidad de los proyectos.

---

***Las Barras:***

**Barras en Rutas (`/` y `\\`):** Las barras son utilizadas en rutas para separar directorios y archivos en la mayoría de los sistemas operativos. Sin embargo, hay diferencias importantes en su uso en sistemas basados en Unix (Linux y macOS) y sistemas basados en Windows.

- En sistemas Unix (Linux, macOS), se utiliza la barra inclinada hacia adelante (`/`) para separar directorios y archivos en las rutas. Por ejemplo: `/carpeta/archivo.txt`.
- En sistemas Windows, la barra inversa (`\`) se usa para separar directorios y archivos. Por ejemplo: `C:\Carpeta\Archivo.txt`.

En la práctica, la mayoría de los lenguajes de programación permiten usar `/` en ambos sistemas, lo que hace que el código sea más portable.

**Barras Dobles (`//`) y Doble Inversa (`\\`):** Las barras dobles se utilizan a menudo para referirse a rutas UNC ([Universal Naming Convention](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/silk-central/210/en/silkcentral-help-en/SCTM-FBADDE47-UNCSOURCECONTROLPROFILES-CON.html)) en sistemas Windows. Estas rutas se utilizan para acceder a recursos compartidos en red. Ejemplo: `\servidor\compartido\archivo.txt`. En la mayoría de los casos, no es necesario preocuparse por las rutas UNC a menos que estés trabajando con recursos compartidos en red en un entorno Windows.

---

***Puntos en Rutas:***

Punto (`.`): El punto se utiliza para representar el directorio actual en una ruta. Por ejemplo, si estás en `/carpeta1` y deseas referirte a un archivo en esa misma carpeta, puedes usar `./archivo.txt` en lugar de `/carpeta1/archivo.txt`. Esto es útil en situaciones donde necesitas especificar la ubicación relativa.

Punto Doble (`..`): El punto doble se usa para representar el directorio padre en una ruta. Por ejemplo, si estás en `/carpeta1` y deseas acceder a un archivo en el directorio padre, puedes usar `../archivo.txt`. Esto te permite navegar **hacia arriba** en la jerarquía de directorios.

---

***Ejemplos de Implementacion:***

- Rutas Absolutas (**Evítalas**): Para referirte a rutas desde la raíz del sistema de archivos, usa `/` en sistemas Unix y `\` en sistemas Windows. Ejemplo:

`/ruta/completa/archivo.txt` se refiere a la ruta completa desde la raíz en sistemas Unix.
`C:\ruta\completa\archivo.txt` se refiere a la ruta completa en sistemas Windows.
Nota: en Windows se requiere colocar el Medio ejemplo: `C:`

- Rutas Relativas (**las que nos interesan**): Para referirte a un archivo o directorio dentro de la misma ubicación, puedes usar `.` para el directorio actual y `..` para el directorio padre. Por ejemplo:

`./archivo.txt` se refiere al archivo en el directorio actual.
`../carpeta/archivo.txt` se refiere a un archivo en la carpeta padre.

y adivina tambien puedes combinarlo:

`./../../carpeta/archivo.txt` asegura la ubicacion actual de trabajo y navega 2 niveles hacia arriba, luego entra a el directorio *carpeta*.

---

El cómo definir rutas de manera efectiva, siguiendo las mejores prácticas, tanto en proyectos personales como en frameworks populares como Laravel, Symfony o CodeIgniter es un conocimiento de suma importancia que estare explicando a continuación:

***Rutas en Proyectos Personales:***

***1. Usar rutas relativas:*** En proyectos personales, es recomendable utilizar rutas relativas en lugar de rutas absolutas. Las rutas relativas permiten que el código sea más portátil entre diferentes sistemas operativos. Por ejemplo:

```php
// Ruta a un archivo en el mismo directorio
include 'archivo.php';

// Ruta a un directorio dentro del proyecto
$imagePath = 'images/';

// Ruta a un directorio padre
$parentDir = '../';
```

***2. Usar constantes para directorios base:*** Definir constantes para los directorios base de tu proyecto, lo que facilitará la gestión de rutas. Por ejemplo:

```php
define('BASE_PATH', __DIR__); // Ruta base de tu proyecto
define('UPLOADS_PATH', BASE_PATH . '/uploads'); // Ruta a la carpeta de subidas
```

***3. Usar la función realpath:*** Si se necesita obtener la ruta completa de un archivo o directorio, puedes utilizar la función realpath. Esto garantiza que obtengas la ruta absoluta correcta en diferentes sistemas operativos.

```php
chdir('/var/www/');
echo realpath('./../../etc/passwd') . PHP_EOL;
```

*output:*

> /etc/passwd

---

***Rutas en Frameworks (Laravel, Symfony, CodeIgniter):***
Nota: no me considero un experto en temas de framework.

***- Configuración en el framework:*** Estos frameworks suelen proporcionar una configuración de rutas en archivos específicos. Se deben definir las rutas dentro de estos archivos de configuración en lugar de rutas estáticas. Esto permite una gestión más eficiente y escalable.

***- Usar funciones y métodos del framework:*** En lugar de manipular rutas directamente, utiliza las funciones y métodos proporcionados por el framework. Por ejemplo, en Laravel, se puedes definir rutas de esta manera:

```
Route::get('/mi-ruta', 'Controlador@metodo');
```

Nota: obviamente esta ruta debe existir y haber sido desarrollada en el proyecto.

***- Usar helpers de ruta:*** La mayoría de los frameworks proporcionan helpers para generar URLs y rutas de manera dinámica. Estos ayudan a mantener la portabilidad. Por ejemplo, en Laravel:

```
$url = route('nombre_de_la_ruta');
```

---

***Otras anotacione personales:***

Ahora cada implementación específica puede variar, por ejemplo es posible que desees definir el separador de directorio en una constante más corta a la que usa php nativamente por ejemplo:

```php
if (!defined('DS')) {
    /**
     * Directory Separator
     *
     * Description: This constant represents the directory separator for the file system paths.
     */

    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}
```

o constantes para la estructura de recursos:

```
if (!defined('PATHS')) {
    /**
     * Path Constant
     *
     * Description: This constant represents the path of the resource and where it is located.
     */

    define('PATHS', ['PUBLIC_SOURCES' => 'assets','HELPERS'=>'Helper']);
}
```

---

Nota: agradezco a la comunidad si desea expandir la información sobre el manejo de Paths, no me considero un experto y es posible que haya dejado a un lado otras consideraciones en las que aún no incursiono.